# HTML,CSS How to click div z-index -1, with href

Tags: html, css

How to click in link with div z-index:-1.

I need one div with z-index -1 in this div is a link , when `z-index` is 1 or larger link in div is clickable, but when i set z-index div to -1 , link is not clickable how to fix it.

CSS

```
.div1 {
      z-index: 1;
}
.div2 {
      z-index: 2;
}
.div3 {
      z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="div3"><a href="">Clickable link with z-index -1</a></div>
```

Comment: You cannot. Period. But why do you wanna do something like that? Looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: Do you want this temporary?

Comment: @VXp i need clickable background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: relative` and have all the elements with a positive `z-index`.

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  position: relative;
}

.div1 {z-index: 3;}

.div2 {z-index: 2;}

.div3 a {z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="div3"><a href="">Clickable link with z-index -1</a></div>
```

Comment: `div3` has `z-index: 1` not `z-index: -1`

Comment: @AlaaMh What did I say in the content of the answer boss? Did you read my answer? I told it is not right to use `z-index: -1`. I mean, **don't use negative `z-index`**.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for the idea, sloved my question