# background overlay and z-index

Tags: background, background-image, overlay, z-index

You know how we make code like below to make an overlay for the background image or color.

HTML

```
<section id="hero">
        <div class="hero container">
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, My Name is </h1>
                <a href="#" type="button" class="cta">Porfolio</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background-image: url(./img/someimg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

}

.container::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .7;
    z-index: -1
}
```

I understand that I have to put z-index to make the anchor tags clickable on the container. But also confused that why the overlay is still showing over the container while we put the z-index to -1.

How come the overlay is visible while the z-index is -1? How come only the text and anchor tag are getting z-index of 1?

Comment: did you get your answer , or do you have another related problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think i got your idea.

As mentioned [here by Sir Praveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47121629/9222942)  , dont use negative z-index, use only positive one i.e z-index:1 and z-index:2 .

```css
.container {
    background-image: url(./img/someimg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

}

.container::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 1;
    
}
```

```html
    <section id="hero">
        <div class="hero container">
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, My Name is </h1>
                <a href="#" type="button" class="cta">Porfolio</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But that wasn't my question :( The . part was just a mistake while I was moving the code here. The question is under my code snippent

Comment: 'But also confused that why the overlay is still showing over the container while we put the z-index to -1' - Do you mean that you need to hide the overlay?

'How come the overlay is visible while the z-index is -1?' - the z-index never meant to hide an element. it is used to specify stack order of an element.

Comment: I never meant to hide the element. As you said z-index is about stack order. And I was purely curious why the pseudo element can still stay above the parent element even though their z-index is lower than it's parent's. I found a good post which figured my question. Have a look if you want to understand what I was talking about! http://www.independent-software.com/set-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-parent-element.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason why pseudo element wasn't entirely under the parent div was because it is a descendants of their associated  element. So if you ever want to put the pseudo elements under the parent element, you will have to consider making another div on top of the parent element. Here is the [post](http://www.independent-software.com/set-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-parent-element.html) that I referred to figure my question.